# do Bitcoin full node onions also relay non-bitcoin traffic?

Tags: security, development, privacy, full-node, raspberry-pi

During the past week or so I am setting up a Bitcoin core full node on Raspberry Pi and making it as secure as possible. In the public mind, the onion sites and Darknet are associated with many things which are illegal. I am trying to figure out how to configure my full node to pass through only the bitcoin related traffic. Is such a configuration possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin nodes cannot relay anything except Bitcoin protocol related P2P messages. You can read the packet capture logs in wireshark while using two regtest nodes with the below steps:

1. Install Wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org/download.html
2. Create two directories for regtest nodes, node1 and node2 with below *bitcoin.conf*:

   ```
   regtest.rpcport=18222
   rpcuser=user1
   rpcpassword=password1
   ```

   ```
   regtest.rpcport=18666
   rpcuser=user2
   rpcpassword=password2
   ```
3. Run node1 and node2 with below commands:

   ```
   bitcoind -regtest=1 -port=18333 -rpcport=18222 -datadir=/home/prayank/node1 -conf=/home/prayank/node1/bitcoin.conf -fallbackfee=0.0001
   ```

   ```
   bitcoind -regtest=1 -port=18777 -rpcport=18666 -datadir=/home/prayank/node2 -conf=/home/prayank/node2/bitcoin.conf -connect=127.0.0.1:18333
   ```
4. Both nodes are running and connected. We can create wallets in each if they don't exist already and generate some bitcoin with `generatetoaddress` RPC
5. Finally, we can try sending bitcoin from node1 to node2 and check p2p message in Wireshark

[image]

*wtxid is highlighted in the above screenshot*

You can also check this video with same steps performed: https://youtu.be/Nb32BISrdnk

> In the public mind, the onion sites and Darknet are associated with many things which are illegal

Cannot change this opinion however illegal things are done using clearnet as well.

> I am trying to figure out how to configure my full node to pass through only the bitcoin related traffic. Is such a configuration possible at all?

If you use Tor as proxy for outbound connections it will not use your real IP address for Bitcoin related P2P messages sent to other nodes. If you setup bitcoin core as [onion service](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/overview/) it will create an onion address for your node that other nodes can use to send Bitcoin related P2P messages.

In both cases the network used is same Tor as used by others for different things however it will be used for only Bitcoin in this context.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prayank, for a quick and detailed step by step answer + demo ! A deep drive in the concepts described at the [Torproject](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec-v3.txt) also helped me a lot in understanding the picture more in details.